# Pickle loading CIFAR-100 data

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, pickle, training-data

I am trying to unpickle the CIFAR-100 data, but I do not think I am doing it correctly. [From their example](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html), you load the file and then call `pickle.load()`:

```
#imports data
def unpickle(file):
    import pickle
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
    return dict
```

But when I run this with the CIFAR-100 data, it fails with:

> dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
>
> TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

When I remove the `encoding` argument, it will err with this:

> X, Y, X_test, Y_test = unpickle("cifar-100-python/train")
>
> ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Basically stating that it retrieved no data from the training file. This is what `dict` returns: `[]`

Here is the code sample:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import cPickle as pickle

#imports data
def unpickle(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo)
    return dict

print(unpickle("cifar-100-python/train")) # <-- This prints []

X, Y, X_test, Y_test = unpickle("cifar-100-python/train")
```

I am running python 2.7.10. Am I missing something?

Comment: May I see output of `print(dict)`. Add it to your Question.

Comment: @stovfl It returns `[]`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  By using the second version of `unpickle` that you wrote and placing the CIFAR-100 `train` pickle file in my current directory: `data = unpickle('train')`, I get `len(data)` being 5 with the following keys: `['data', 'batch_label', 'fine_labels', 'coarse_labels', 'filenames']`.  As such, I get a dictionary with 5 keys.  The `shape` of the data (i.e. `data['data'].shape`) is a 50000 x 3072 `numpy` array as expected.  BTW, the `encoding` parameter is only for Python 3.  Github gist containing output: https://gist.github.com/rayryeng/221c6f291a5011625f15ef969392ab28

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for double checking... I think I had a bad download, because after reading your comment I redownloaded the file and unpacked. It now works; had me stumped for a while :( If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah I figured it was a bad download. No problem at all! I'll write on soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion in the comments, it looks like you had a bad download.  I downloaded the CIFAR-100 database from the link you provided above, used the second version of `unpickle` that you provided and loaded in the data successfully.  Note that the `'encoding'` parameter is only valid for Python 3 so I used the second version you provided as it works for Python 2.

Specifically, using the `train` pickle file that I extracted from the archive and placed in my current directory, here's my REPL history:

```
In [14]: import cPickle as pickle

In [15]: def unpickle(file):
    ...:     with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
    ...:         dict = pickle.load(fo)
    ...:     return dict
    ...:

In [16]: data = unpickle('train')

In [17]: len(data)
Out[17]: 5

In [18]: data.keys()
Out[18]: ['data', 'batch_label', 'fine_labels', 'coarse_labels', 'filenames']

In [19]: data['data'].shape
Out[19]: (50000L, 3072L)
```

As you can see, I get a dictionary with 5 keys.  The value stored with the `'data'` key in the dictionary contains our 32 x 32 colour pixel data where each row is an unrolled version of an image (32 x 32 x 3 colour channels = 3072 pixels).  There are also 50000 images as we expect.  As such, try downloading the data again and use your `unpickle` function - the second one that you provided.  It should work like it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a solution which works for both Python 2.x and 3.x.

```
import pickle
with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
    try:
        samples = pickle.load(fo)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:  #python 3.x
        fo.seek(0)
        samples = pickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def unpickle(file):
import cPickle
with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
    dict = cPickle.load(fo)
return dict
dict=unpickle("file")
print dict['data']
```

use dict['data'] for getting all the images

Comment: This doesn't work. If I remove the `encoding` part, `dict` just becomes `[]`, which is why I get that error about being unable to unpack 0 values.

Comment: if you are using python version 3 then use encoding parameter in pickle.load() and check out the code (https://github.com/mila-udem/fuel/blob/master/fuel/converters/cifar100.py) hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
def unpickle(file):
    import pickle
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
    return dict
```

with:

```
def unpickle(file):
    import cPickle
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = cPickle.load(fo)
    return dict
```